# Control rsync user and group on reciever side

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync

I have an rsync command to backup a directory from a remote server to a local NAS on my LAN, mounted on my server.
I am using con to invoke the command

```
rsync --rsh='ssh -pxxx' -rultxz xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/path/to/directory/ /media/mountpoint/directory/
```

The problem is that the directories are not recieving propper perms, and that is screwing with the transfer. This is what happens:
The mountpoint has permission 777

The first created folder gets 744

RSync fails as it can't add more files and directories with

```
mkdir: Permission denied (13)
```

The folders are being created locally with a userid that doesn't exist on the system (1028) and a group that doesn't exist either. I am guessing these are from the remote location.

The question is:
How do I control the created folder/file permissions on the receiving side so I can map them to a local user, and set permissions?

I tried using the -p flag, and

```
--chmod=u+rwx,g+rwx,o+r
```

but that made no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the mount itself. The user who invoked RSync through cron was not the owner of the mountpoint, and therefore, could not change the permissions/owner of the directories. That created the situation where the user created folders that it could not read.

The solution was to add --super to the command and include the user in the sudo group(And restart)